# Persisting Lists in Model from View to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, listbox, models

I am pretty new to ASP.NET MVC so please be patient with me.  I am having problems persisting a list in my model back to the controller when a user submits the form.

Here is a the scenario: 
This is a web app that allows users to create estimates for translation jobs.  Each estimate has a list of language pairs.  To give the users the ability to add languages pairs they need a list of all available language pairs.

My model looks something like this:

```
public class EstimateModel
{
    public tblEstimate Estimate { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<tblEstimateLangPair> EstimateLanguagePairs { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<tblLangPair> LanguagePairs { get; set; }

    public EstimateModel()
    {
        Estimate = new tblEstimate();
        EstimateLanguagePairs = new List<tblEstimateLangPair>();
        LanguagePairs = new List<tblLangPair>();
    }
}
```

This is basically a wrapper for objects that were created by the Entity Framework.  In my controller I hydrate the estimate object and the two language pair lists and pass it to the view like so:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int estimateID)
{
    EstimateModel model = new EstimateModel();

    model.Estimate = db.tblEstimates.Single(t => t.EstimateID == estimateID);

    model.LanguagePairs = db.tblLangPairs.ToList();

    var query = from e in db.tblEstimateLangPairs
                join lp in db.tblLangPairs on e.LangPairID equals lp.ProductID
                where e.EstimateID == estimateID
                select new { e.EstimateID, e.LangPairID, lp.Language_pairs};

    model.EstimateLanguagePairs = query.ToList().ConvertAll(p => new tblEstimateLangPair
    {
        EstimateID = p.EstimateID,
        LangPairID = p.LangPairID,
        Language_pairs = p.Language_pairs
    });

    return PartialView(model);
}
```

In my 'partial' view I have controls for estimate object and for the language pair lists:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Estimate.JobNumber)%>
<%= Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.LanguagePairs, new SelectList(Model.LanguagePairs, "LangPairID", "Language_pairs"))%>
<%= Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.EstimateLanguagePairs, new SelectList(Model.EstimateLanguagePairs, "LangPairID", "Language_pairs"))%>
```

So far so good.  I can populate these list boxes just.  I can step through the controller code and see that my model has data there for all these object in my model that I am passing to the view.

My problem is when I try to submit this back to the controller to save any changes.  The Model.Estimate object has no problem persisting all of it's properties back to the controller.  When I look at the model in the controller method that will save changes, I see the list objects but their count is zero.

Save method in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditEstimate(EstimateModel model)
{
    db.tblEstimates.Attach(model.Estimate);
    db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(model.Estimate, EntityState.Modified);

    foreach (tblEstimateLangPair langPair in model.EstimateLanguagePairs)
    {
        db.tblEstimateLangPairs.Attach(langPair);
        db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(langPair, EntityState.Modified);
    }

    db.SaveChanges();

    return Redirect("/Home/Index");
}
```

How do you persist lists, or collections in a model back to the controller when submitting form data?  I believe my problem somewhere lies in how I use these ListBoxFor objects.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First load fiddler and watch your request being sent over. I'm guessing all the items from your listbox are not being posted - in that case there will be no model binding with it.

Comment: I am using localhost right now, so fiddler is not an option for me.  When a web server becomes available, I will try this.  Thanks!  (sorry I am new to stackoverflow and apparently can't give you any points yet.)

Comment: you surely can use fiddler locally - load fiddler and you can try ipv4.fiddler as your hostname - it will map through fiddler. if using IE just use "localhost./whatever" note the dot, or use your machine name.